# Looking for files NOT owned by a specific user

Tags: linux, file, shell, search

I'm looking to recursively look through directories to find files NOT owned by a particular user and I am not sure how to write this.

Answer (score 335, accepted):

The find(1) utility has primaries that can be negated ("reversed") using the "!" operator. On the prompt one must however escape the negation with a backslash as it is a shell metacharacter. Result:

```
find . \! -user foo -print
```

Comment: escaping the `!` seems to be optional

Comment: piping the output to `xargs ls -al` can provide more info than the `-print` flag

Comment: piping the output to `xargs -I{} -P3 -- ${cmdhere} {}` can have ${cmdhere} operate on each file in parallel. cmdhere ::= standard unix utils; standard unix utils ::= chmod, chown, stat, ls, ...

Comment: @sorin do you mean the `find . ...` or piping to `xargs` the first or second way?

Comment: find has the -exec flag ->   `find .  ! -user  foo  -exec chown <owner>:<group> {} \;`

Comment: xargs can provide a significant performance boost .v. -exec, since chown can take a list of many files to chown on the same command like, saving the cost of many execs.

Comment: how to add owner info as output?

Comment: I used `-not` to avoid escaping the `!` but apparently it isn't POSIX compliant. From the man page: `-not expr   Same as ! expr, but not POSIX compliant.`.

Comment: @Silentbang did you ever figure that out? i would like to know as well

Comment: @Anthony Use printf option to get it along with file name: `find . \! -user foo -printf '%p - %u\n'`. Actually I just found out by reading the 'find' command manual as you reminded me.

Comment: thanks! And @Sorin, it does work recursively for me (centos 7 : find /path \! -user myUser)

Comment: @sorin: The exclamation point must be escaped if Bash history is active (`set -H`) which is usually on by default.

Answer (score 46):

> Looking for files NOT owned by someone

Others have answered the question *"NOT owned by a particular user"* in the body. Here's one that answers the titular question but has not been provided:

```
$ find / -nouser
```

You can use it like so:

```
$ sudo find /var/www -nouser -exec chown root:apache {} \;
```

And a related one:

```
$ find / -nogroup
```

Comment: I'll give you a vote for the technicality, but people would generally say "not owned by anyone" if they meant what you were interpreting.

Comment: @Shibumi - Yeah, sounds about right for those splitting hairs. The problem I faced was, I needed to find files literally not owned by any user. It surfaced after a web server refresh and migration. Some user/group ids changed so I needed to script a chown.

Answer (score 12):

You can use this:

```
find <dir> ! -user <username>
```

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't add anything to the accepted answer, and it masks other possible answers (such as the zsh glob pattern below).

Comment: This answer was given 3 minutes after the accepted answer. People deserve credit for giving answers and they are not psychic.

Answer (score 10):

`-user` finds by user or user ID, and `!` inverts the predicate. So, `! -user ...`.

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't add anything to the accepted answer, and it masks other possible answers (such as the zsh glob pattern below).

Answer (score 6):

Using z-shell (zsh) you can use

```
ls -laR *(^U)
```

or

```
ls -la **/*(^U)
```

to search for all files recursively not owned by you.

Comment: It is true that the command above will not list dot files, even with the `-a` flag because of the wildcard expansion. To catch dot files use the zsh `dotglob` option: `setopt dotglob`. In one line: `(setopt dotglob; ls **/*(^U) )`. The parentheses are to run in a subshell so that you don't have to run `setopt nodotglob` after you've finished.

Comment: @Zorawar You can also add `D` to the parenthesis: `ls **/*(D^U)`.

Comment: @MarcCornellà You're right; I did not know that. Thank you. That's a much better option than having to use setopt if it will be a one-time usage.