# Chef user group permissions on subfolders

Tags: ruby, linux, chef-infra, chef-recipe, subdirectory

I am working trying to give user group permissions on subfolders in a Linux environment. In Linux that would be:

```
chown -R user:group /var/lib/temp/*
```

How can I acheive the same in Chef with Ruby? I have tried this:

```
directory '/opt/jenkins/plugins' do
  owner 'jenkins'
  group 'jenkins'
  mode '0755'
  recursive true
  action :create
end
```

By specifying recursive it does not help.

Comment: You can refer :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921708/how-do-i-change-recursively-the-owner-and-group-on-a-directory-with-chef

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change recursively the owner and group on a directory with Chef?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921708/how-do-i-change-recursively-the-owner-and-group-on-a-directory-with-chef)?

Answer (score 0):

From the [chef docs](https://docs.chef.io/resource_directory.html):

```
recursive
    Ruby Types: TrueClass, FalseClass

    Create or delete parent directories recursively. For the owner, group, and mode properties, the value of this attribute applies only to the leaf directory. Default value: false.
```

User and group permissions won't recurse, you'll have to set them on each sub-directory manually.

You could make this slightly easier by doing something like the following:

```
plugins = %w(plugin1 plugin2)
plugins.each do |plugin|
  directory "/opt/jenkins/plugins/#{plugin}" do
    owner 'jenkins'
    group 'jenkins'
    mode '0755'
    action :create
  end
end
```

Comment: I do not want to define each subfolder. Since there are a bunch of them and a long hierarchi of folders.